# AWS equivalent of system.out.println()?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, debugging, servlets

I am working on a Java Web Application and I'm deploying it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Can I write system.out.println() (or similar) and view it when the application is deployed? If so, where is the log?

I would like this for debugging purposes, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your `system.out.println()` question, yes you can use this and it will show up in the logs.

Whilst setting up the Elastic Beanstalk application, you were asked for a KEY. This is the key you can use to `ssh` into your the instance where you can find the logs in `/var/log`. Look for a file called `web-1.inf` or `catalina.out`. (don't quote me on this)

Another location where you can check the logs is when you select your Elastic Beanstalk application in the Elastic Beanstalk Dashboard, and on the left-hand side select `LOGS`. Here you can select whether you want the FULL logs which is a zipped version of all the logs on the instance OR you can select the get the last 100 lines of output coming from your application.

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't see the wood for the trees!